# ReactJS by creating body dynamically

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use ReactJS, and I understand the implication of running ReactJS from directly modifying body tag, that it can be overwritten by other apps, and causes weird errors. Therefore it is a good practice to put it into a `div`.

https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375

> **Don’t Render to Body**
>
> So what’s the other mistake I wanted to tell you
>   about? It’s much simpler: don’t ever render to document.body. A lot of
>   React examples do that because it’s less typing and looks more clear.
>   Don’t. Do. This.
>
> React wants to fully manage DOM tree under its
>   control. If you append something foreign inside a DOM tree managed by
>   React, it might seriously freak out, unless you do it very carefully
>   (e.g. inside a leaf component that has shouldComponentUpdate returning
>   false).
>
> What’s the problem with ? Everybody updates it! Some
>   people have non-React code that attaches modals to it. Google Font
>   Loader will happily put  elements into body for a fraction of
>   second, and your app will break horribly and inexplicably if it tries
>   to update something on the top level during that time. Do you really
>   know what all your third party scripts are doing? What about ads or
>   that social network SDK?
>
> Finally, consider something you have no
>   control over: browser plugins. Yes, they can inject stuff into .
>   Of course they can also mess with the rest of the DOM, but at least
>   you can fix the most widespread case.
>
> So what do you do? Always put a
>   root  into , give it an ID and render into it. Another
>   advantage of doing so is that you can put your scripts at the bottom
>   of the  and you won’t need to wait for DOMContentLoaded before
>   rendering.

But I wonder if I make something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <div id="my-app" />,
   document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
);

ReactDOM.render(
   <App />,
   document.getElementById('my-app')
);
```

into `<body/>` instead of

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('my-app')
);
```

into `<body><div id="my-app" /></body>`

Will this approach have the same problem as

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
);
```

into `<body />`

Thank you

Comment: "Will this approach have the same problem?" yes. Your first div will replace everything in body.

Comment: I am sorry, I have clarified my question. I mean, if you put React apps into body tag, we could have some unforeseen and weird bugs  that are difficult to debug. Since other apps sometimes modified our body tag too. So it is advised to put it into `div`. But I wonder, if I create `div` tag from inside react-dom, will it cause the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand if that code create weird errors which cannot be debugged, that code is not properly written.

There are some situations (especially in FLUX) where you emit events to an component which is not mounted yet and it doesn't give any error.

Comment: What I meant, is this. Check the lower part
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375

Comment: Couple of things.
1. It's about issues happening when loading two versions of React (which you shouldn't do anyway).
2. Don't need to render to the body anyway. Just render to a div which is inside the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Like below. No need to render to the body tag anyways.

```
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bundle.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

And the React code will look like this

```
const app = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Layout/>, app);
```

Comment: I know if I can create it like that. But I just wonder, if I make something like `ReactDOM.render(id="root" />,.getElementsByTagName("body")[0])` into `<body/>` instead writing it into `<body><div id="root"/><body>`, will it have the same problem?